# At what point exactly does a SOAPHandler intercept outgoing messages

Tags: java, jax-ws, soaphandler

I'm using SOAPHandler.handleMessage(...) to intercept outgoint SOAP messages from client to server.

I need to confirm that the interception takes place after the message has been sent. Not sure if this is really the case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple trick to check your assumption. Add this code in `handleMessage` method:

```
    SOAPMessage msg = ((SOAPMessageContext) context).getMessage();
    SOAPPart sp = msg.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope env = sp.getEnvelope();
```

Now when you have a `SOAPEnvelope` try to alternate SOAP message and see what happens when receiver receives it. I will spoil the surprise and reveal you: it will be changed :-)
Thus, your SOAPHandler intercepts the message before it's actually sent.